# Codeception get webdriver sessionId

Tags: webdriver, codeception

I'm using `Codeception` with the `WebDriver` module and I want to access the webdriver's `sessionId` in the `_beforeSuite` helper's function.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible not in the `_beforeSuite` function, but in the `_before` and `_after` functions, like this:

```
public function _before(\Codeception\TestCase $test)
{     
    $sessionId = $this->getModule('WebDriver')->webDriver->getSessionID();
}
```